# Show the active site in an iframe as an extension to the parent page url

Tags: javascript, iframe

So I'm building this register with a menu to the left and an iframe to the right. Everything works perfectly with the iframe and navigation, but there's one thing missing.

I would like to have the url of the parent page change from: "address.com/help" to for example: "address.com/help/unicorn" when I click on the "unicorn.html" link to the left in the navigation. I.e, make the active site in the iframe become an extension of the parent url.

I've seen the

```
var iframe     = $('iframe');
var contentWnd = iframe.attr('contentWindow');
var url = contentWnd.window.location.href;

window.location.hash = url;
```

on a different thread, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: Does your iFrame have an attribute named contentWindow which is filled?

Comment: And you're sure the contentWindow attribute has window.location.href defined? I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to this, and I still can't get it to work. The site I'm making is "igems.se/help14.3". Let's say I want to look at the line command (CAD/Line). When clicking this link, I want the parent url to change to igems.se/help14.3/line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method)